# Svelte - using select inputs with an on:change event

Tags: drop-down-menu, svelte

Still very new to svelte (but learning more each day!) and need a bit of help.

I am working on a veterinary drug dose calculator that calculates the individual dose of each drug based on the concentration of each drug, the mg/kg dosage of that drug and the weight in kilograms of the patient. I have a weight converter for lbs <-> kgs and my calculations will work if I have just one concentration. The issue is that many drugs have multiple concentrations so I need a select input to allow the user to change the concentration for each drug.

Here is a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/60a83d15426e4b378013a67131df3994?version=3.12.1)

Here is my Code:

```
    <div class="row no-gap">
  <div class="col-50  tablet-25">
    <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline item-input-with-value">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title item-label">Pounds</div>
        <div class="item-input-wrap">
          <input value={l} on:input="{e => setBothFromL(e.target.value)}" min="0" type=number placeholder=" lbs">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-50 tablet-25">
    <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline item-input-with-value">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title item-label">Kilogram</div>
        <div class="item-input-wrap">
          <input value={k} on:input="{e => setBothFromK(e.target.value)}" min="0" type=number placeholder="kgs">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<h1>Antibiotics</h1>
{#each antibiotics as antibiotic, i}
<div class="Rtable-row eachdrug eachdrugE" data-id="{i + 1}">
  <div class="Rtable-cell drug-cell">
    <span class="drugTitle searchme">{antibiotic.name}
      {#if antibiotic.concSelect.length === 1}
      {antibiotic.concentration} {antibiotic.perml}
      {:else if antibiotic.concSelect.length > 1}

      <select bind:value={selected} on:change="{() => concs = selected}">


        {#each antibiotic.concSelect as concSelect}
        <option value={concSelect.conc}>
          {concSelect.name}
        </option>
        {/each}

      </select>
      {/if}

    </span>

  </div>
</div>
<div>

  <div>
    Dose: <input bind:value={antibiotic.dosevalue} step={antibiotic.dosestep} min="{antibiotic.dosemin}" max="{antibiotic.dosemax}" type=number>

    {#if  antibiotic.dosevalue > antibiotic.dosemax * 1.1 }
    <span class="error-message1 hidden-print" transition:fly="{{ y: 10, duration: 500 }}"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-sm fa-fw hidden-print" data-fa-transform="up-2"></i> Above Range</span>
    {/if}

  </div>
  <div> <span class="vol">{(k *   antibiotic.dosevalue).toFixed(antibiotic.decimal)} {antibiotic.appendose}</span>
  <span class="vol">{#if antibiotic.concSelect.length === 1}
{((k * antibiotic.dosevalue) / antibiotic.concentration).toFixed(antibiotic.decimal)} {antibiotic.appendvol}
 {:else if antibiotic.concSelect.length > 1}
{((k * antibiotic.dosevalue) / concs).toFixed(antibiotic.decimal)} {antibiotic.appendvol}
{/if} </span></div>
</div>


{/each}
<style>
input{min-width:120px}
.vol {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .12); padding:5px;}
.error-message1 {
font-size: 10px !important;
line-height: 11px !important;
font-weight: normal;
color: red;
opacity: 0.5;
font-weight: 700;
}
.eachdrug {border-top: 1px solid #ccc; margin-top:15px}
</style>

<script>
import { fade, fly } from 'svelte/transition';
let k = '';
let l = '' ;
let selected;
let concs ="";

function setBothFromK(value) {
k = +value;
l = +( k * 2.2046226218).toFixed(1);
}
function setBothFromL(value) {
l = +value;
k = +( l / 2.2046226218).toFixed(1);
}

let antibiotics = [
    {  
 "group":"",
   "route":"IV,IM,SQ BID",
   "perml":"mg/ml",
   "concentration":"50",
    "concSelect": [
        { "conc": 50, "name": "50 mg/ml","perml": "ml" }
        ],
   "perkg":"mg/kg",
   "doseper":"10",
   "dosemin":"10",
   "dosemax":"30",
   "dosestep":"1",
   "dosevalue":"10",
   "hide":"",
   "name":"Amikacin",
   "calc":"Amikacin",
   "calcID":"Amikacin2",
   "decimal": "2",
   "appendose": " mg",
   "appendvol": " ml",
   "multiply": "",
   "class": "drug",
   "color": "green"
},
{
"group":"",
"route":"BID",
"perml":"mg/ml",
"concentration":"50",
"concSelect": [
{"id": 1 , "conc": 50, "name": "50 mg/ml","perml": "ml" },
{"id": 2 , "conc": 100, "name": "100 mg/ml","perml": "" },
{"id": 3 , "conc": 150, "name": "150 mg/ml","perml": "" },
{"id": 4 , "conc": 200, "name": "200 mg/ml","perml": "" },
{"id": 5 , "conc": 400, "name": "400 mg/ml","perml": "" }
],
"perkg":"mg/kg",
"doseper":"11",
"dosemin":"11",
"dosemax":"22",
"dosestep":"1",
"dosevalue":"11",
"hide":"",
"name":"Amoxicillin",
"decimal": "2",
"appendose": " mg",
"appendvol": " ml",
"class": "drug"
},
{
"group":"",
"route":"BID",
"perml":"mg/ml",
"concentration":"62.5",
"concSelect": [
{"id": 1 , "conc": 62.5, "name": "62.5","perml": "ml" },
{"id": 2, "conc": 125, "name": "125","perml": "" },
{"id":3 , "conc": 250, "name": "250","perml": "" },
{"id": 4, "conc": 375, "name": "375","perml": "" }
],
"perkg":"mg/kg",
"doseper":"13.75",
"dosemin":"13.75",
"dosemax":"25",
"dosestep":"1",
"dosevalue":"13.75",
"hide":"",
"name":"Amoxicillin-Clavulanate",
"calc":"Amoxicillin-Clavulanate",
"calcID":"Amoxicillin-Clavulanate2",
"decimal": "2",
"appendose": " mg",
"appendvol": " ml",
"class": "drug",
},
{
"group":"",
"route":"BID",
"perml":"mg/ml",
"concentration":"100",
"concSelect": [
{"id": 1 , "conc": 100, "name": "100","perml": "ml" },
{"id": 2 , "conc": 125, "name": "125","perml": "" },
{"id": 3 , "conc": 250, "name": "250","perml": "" },
{ "id": 4 ,"conc": 500, "name": "500","perml": "" }
],
"perkg":"mg/kg",
"doseper":"6.6",
"dosemin":"6.6",
"dosemax":"22",
"dosestep":"1",
"dosevalue":"6.6",
"hide":"",
"name":"Ampicillin",
"calc":"Ampicillin",
"calcID":"Ampicillin2",
"decimal": "2",
"appendose": " mg",
"appendvol": " ml",
"class": "drug"
}
];1
</script>
```

The problems are :

1. On page load, the select option value is not initially utilized in the drug dose equation ( I get NaN or Infinity). After selecting, it is.
2. Changing the select option changes all of the drug concentrations, not just the individual drug concentration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have one of the following for each antibiotic:

```js
<select bind:value={selected} on:change="{() => concs = selected}">
...
</select>
```

Your `on:change` handler is not necessary here, since it's a simple assignment. So you could just `bind:value={concs}` which would be exactly the same. You're using two variables where you could use a single one. This is also the reason why you're seeing `NaN` values, because your `concs` variable is not set until you *change* the selected option. By binding directly to the tracking variable, you're solving that first issue.

However, you're also using a single variable (or variable pair, as seen above) to track changes in several *distinct* select fields, and that's where your real problem lies. For each of these select fields, you want a different variable to track its selected value.

You can easily do this by adding a `concs` key to each `antibiotic` and setting it to what you want your default value to be, then updating your select fields to use that new variable, using the simplified binding, and finally updating the line where you rely on that value for your concentration computation:

```js
<select bind:value={antibiotic.concs}>
...
</select>
...
{#if antibiotic.concSelect.length === 1}
  ...
{:else if antibiotic.concSelect.length > 1}
  {((k * antibiotic.dosevalue) / antibiotic.concs).toFixed(antibiotic.decimal)}{antibiotic.appendvol}
{/if}
...

<script>
...
let antibiotics = [
  {
    ...
    "concs": 50,
  },
  {
    ...
    "concs": 100,
  },
  {
    ...
    "concs": 62.5,
  },
  {
    ...
    "concs": 100,
  },
]
...
</script>
```

[Working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/690e37d0ce6e48ed82e3877a8a743935?version=3.12.1)

Comment: An additional newbie question. If I want to access the 2nd drugs input value, `bind:value={antibiotic.dosevalue}` ,how can I do that? I tried antibiotic.dosevalue[1], but that is not obviously the correct way.

Comment: @Macsupport If you're trying to access it from within your `each` loop, then it's simply `{antibiotic.dosevalue}`. `dosevalue` is not an array, it is a key on each of your `antibiotic` objects. If you're trying to access it from *outside* the `each` loop, then you'll have to specify which antibiotics' object you want to read the dosevalue of. For instance, for the 2nd antibiotic in the list, that would be `{antibiotics[1].dosevalue}` (note the **s** in antibiotics, we're referencing the whole array here).

Comment: @Macsupport Also, if you have a work-in-progress REPL and tell me what you're trying to do, I'll be happy to help if I can ;)

Comment: Thanks! What I'm working on is a bit more convoluted, for me at least. Here is the  [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f4d827d032d14d77904cb7b84be012fb?version=3.12.1) I added some explanation on the REPL